# Java ArrayList Elements Removing Themselves And Each Other

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

My problem is fairly simple, I have an ArrayList of bodies (called bodies), and it gets updated, passing the list into each element. There are situations where a body will need to destroy itself and another body in the ArrayList. I have them committing "suicide" with an `isRequestingDeath` Boolean, and I can successfully remove them as on line 7, and for a body removing other bodies, it sets the integer `requestedMurder` to the other body's position in the bodies list. and then using the `bodies` ArrayList `remove()` method to attempt to remove that element (or in this case "body").

```
for(Iterator<Body> bodyIt = bodies.iterator(); bodyIt.hasNext();) {
    Body body = bodyIt.next();
    body.Update(bodies, gravConstant);

    if(body.isRequestingDeath) {
        bodies.remove(body.requestedMurder);
        bodyIt.remove();
    }
}
```

the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
     at gravity.SimApp.Update(SimApp.java:67)
     at gravity.SimApp.Loop(SimApp.java:53)
     at gravity.SimApp.<init>(SimApp.java:42)
     at gravity.SimApp.main(SimApp.java:86)
```

Is there any way to fix my method? Or is there a better way for elements in an ArrayList to remove themselves/each other

Answer (score 0):

CME means just that: two or more things were trying to modify `bodies` at once. That is not apparent in your code (which looks perfectly fine), but that is the definition of the error `Exception`.

My guess is that `bodies` works in the "Model" component of a [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture (a game, perhaps?) and that it is being concurrently modified elsewhere, e.g. by the controller. Try to find a way to streamline your software to avoid concurrent modifications (e.g. event-based) or synchronize `bodies`, manually or via [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this line:

```
bodies.remove(body.requestedMurder);
```

Since you're trying to remove an element from underlying collection here. `Iterator#remove()` is the only safe way to remove an item from underlying collection during iteration. Behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while in iteration.

**To fix this you can populate a separate list of items to be removed like this:**

```
List<Body> bodiesToRemove = new ArrayList<Body>();
for(Iterator<Body> bodyIt = bodies.iterator(); bodyIt.hasNext();) {
    Body body = bodyIt.next();
    body.Update(bodies, gravConstant);

    if(body.isRequestingDeath) {
        bodiesToRemove.add(body); // add in to be removed list
        bodyIt.remove();
    }
}

// now remove all from original list
bodies.removeAll( bodiesToRemove );
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem seems ok, but it appears logically wrong as per java collection behaviour.
for example :
requestedMurder is the position value for othe element in the list, which may not be correct after removal of any element as the list will be shrinked.

So i think although it is not possible to remove self and other element at same time using position value as per your "Body" object.... please correct me if i am not correct.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just applying the necessary edits to the copy of `bodies` passed into each body, and it worked fine. (though I am unsure if this is proper/safe)